# Saving markers with Google Map Api - redirecting to .php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a site that uses google maps api to add and save markers to a php database. When a new marker is added to the map, it open up an InfoWindow which displays a Form for submitting data and saving it to the db.

The Form is:

```
var WinnerForm = '<p><div class="winner-form">'+
            '<form action="addwinner.php" method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
            '<label for="w_name"><span>Winner Name :</span><input type="text" name="w_name" class="save-name" placeholder="Name of Winner" maxlength="40"/></label>'+
            '<label for="w_address"><span>Address :</span><textarea name="w_address" class="save-address" placeholder="Address of Winner" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+
            '<label for="w_description"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="w_description" class="save-desc" placeholder="Dewscription of Award" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+

            '<button name="save-winner" class="save-winner btn btn-info btn-sm style="float:left">Save Winner<br>' +
            '<button name="cancel-winner" class="cancel-winner btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="float:right">Cancel winner</button>' +
            '</div>';
            //Drop a new Marker with the Winner Form
            new_winner_marker(event.latLng, 'New Winner', WinnerForm, '', '', '', true, true, true, "static/assets/new_winner_icon.png");
```

The script that displays this form is:

```
function new_winner_marker(MapPos, wName, wForm, wDesc, wMonth, wYear, InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, InfoOpenDefault, iconPath)
{

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        title: wName,
        icon: iconPath
    });

    // Store the name info as a marker properties 
    marker.myname = wName;
    winner_markers.push(marker);

    // Content to be displayed in winner InfoWindows
    var winnerContent = $(
        '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
        '<h3 class="winner-heading">'+wName+'</h3><br>'+
        wForm +
        '</div></div>'); 

    // Open Info window by default to add form
    infowindow.setContent(winnerContent[0]);
```

The Save button, when pressed with the form should save the details and save the marker. It saves the data OK to the db, but instead of showing the new marker on the map, it opens up the blank PHP in the browser. I also have it so if the field Name is left blank, it opens a pop-up (bootstrap modal) saying that Name cannot be blank. But again, this does not happen, it just redirects to addwinners.php:

```
var saveBtn = winnerContent.find('button.save-winner')[0];

if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
    {
        //add click listner to save marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
            var mReplace = winnerContent.find('span.info-content'); 
            var wName = winnerContent.find('input.save-name')[0].value;
            var wAdd  = winnerContent.find('textarea.save-address')[0].value; 
            var wDesc  = winnerContent.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; 
            var wMonth = winnerContent.find('select.save-month')[0].value;
            var wYear = winnerContent.find('select.save-year')[0].value; 

            if(wName =='')
            {
                $("#myModal-save").modal('show,', 100);

            }else{
                save_winner(marker, wName, wAdd, wDesc, wMonth, wYear, mReplace); //call save marker function
            }
```

The function that saves the data is sent using ajax to the php script:

```
function save_winner(Marker, wName, wAdd, wDesc, wMonth, wYear, replaceWin)
{
    //Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
    var mLatLang = Marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
    var myData = {name : wName, address : wAdd, about : wDesc, latlang : mLatLang, month : wMonth, year: wYear }; //post variables

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "addwinner.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
            replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
            $("#winner-saved").slideDown();
            Marker.setDraggable(false); //set marker to fixed

            infowindow.setContent('Winner Added');
            setTimeout(function () {infowindow.close();}, 3000); // Close info window after 3 seconds
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your form has an action url and a method on it. Then you make an ajax request where you specify a url and a method, which could be completely different from those on the form tag.

The ajax request happening doesn't prevent the original form submission happening.

On the submit button event handler, either do `event.preventDefault()` and/or `return false` to stop the form submission (but still allowing for your ajax post).

Also I'd recommend removing the action and method attributes from the form tag, to prevent possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. using `event.preventDefault();` helped solve this, but also i had an error with `$("#myModal-winner").modal('show,' 100);` - There was a comma after show, in the parenthesis, so had to be changed to:

```
$("#myModal-winner").modal('show', 100);
```